# Gradle heap error on uploadArchives

Tags: gradle

I am trying to upload an archive that's 600MB in size.

I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Java heap space
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have tried to set GRADLE_OPTS, JVM_OPTS and MAVEN_OPTS variables, for setting the max. heap size, like for example:

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
gradle uploadArchives
```

But I am still getting the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using the wrapper by any chance?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko sadly no, I'm not.

Comment: if the gradle daemon is activated, the JVM memory options should be set in the user properties file "~/.gradle/gradle.properties" (for example, set property "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx512m")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the actual size of package was a lot higher due to gradle not being able to handle symlinks.

When I manually handled the symlinks, the problem ended.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you always have a finite max of heap to use no matter what platform you are running on. In Windows 32 bit this is around 2gb (not specifically heap but total amount of memory per process). It just happens that Java happens to make the default smaller (presumably so that the programmer can't create programs that have runaway memory allocation without running into this problem and having to examine exactly what they are doing).

So this given there are several approaches you could take to either determine what amount of memory you need or to reduce the amount of memory you are using. One common mistake with garbage collected languages such as Java or C# is to keep around references to objects that you no longer are using, or allocating many objects when you could reuse them instead. As long as objects have a reference to them they will continue to use heap space as the garbage collector will not delete them.

In this case you can use a Java memory profiler to determine what methods in your program are allocating large number of objects and then determine if there is a way to make sure they are no longer referenced, or to not allocate them in the first place. One option which I have used in the past is "JMP" http://www.khelekore.org/jmp/.

If you determine that you are allocating these objects for a reason and you need to keep around references (depending on what you are doing this might be the case), you will just need to increase the max heap size when you start the program. However, once you do the memory profiling and understand how your objects are getting allocated you should have a better idea about how much memory you need.

In general if you can't guarantee that your program will run in some finite amount of memory (perhaps depending on input size) you will always run into this problem. Only after exhausting all of this will you need to look into caching objects out to disk etc. At this point you should have a very good reason to say "I need Xgb of memory" for something and you can't work around it by improving your algorithms or memory allocation patterns. Generally this will only usually be the case for algorithms operating on large datasets (like a database or some scientific analysis program) and then techniques like caching and memory mapped IO become useful.

Run Java with the command-line option `-Xmx`, which sets the maximum size of the heap.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#nonstandard

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. As you see, I'm using 'uploadArchives' function of 'maven' plugin of 'gradle'. I am unable to control when and how the program wishes to use the memory.  All I have in my hand is a large archive, and a heap that it doesn't fit. The -Xmx option, as I said in the question, doesn't work.

Comment: I use existing code provided by gradle, and allocation/deallocation are none of my bussiness.    
I have figured that the reason why the archive was large is because gradle can't handle symlinks. I have solved that, and I'm not having this problem any longer.

Answer (score -1):

The JVM heap size can be set in the `gradle.properties` file, in the root directory of your gradle project. Like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Hi Sherlock; your answer is quite short, and difficult to understand. You should make it better by adding more description, in particular explaining how it solves the questioner's problem; and also it would be useful to use markdown to format your code snippet.